# Hibernate detached entity passed to persist

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

None of the similar questions on this site have been able to resolve my problem.

**Error:** org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: healthcheckapi.model.Checks

I am trying to use Hibernate (JPA) to persist two objects to a MYSQL database. "Health" has a oneToMany relationship with "Checks".

**Code:**

Health Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="health")
public class Health {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String server;
    private String description;
    private String timestamp;
    private String offset;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "health")
    private List<Checks> checks;

    public Health() {

    }

    public Health(int id, String server, String description, String timestamp, String offset, List<Checks> checks) {

        this.server = server;
        this.description = description;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.offset = offset;
        this.checks = checks;
    }
```

Checks Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="checks")
public class Checks {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int status;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "healthid", referencedColumnName="id")
    private Health health;

    public Checks() {

    }

    public Checks(String name, int status) {

        this.name = name;
        this.status = status;
    }
```

Sample JSON Health Object:

```
{
    "server": "Server18",
    "description": "Fine",
    "timestamp": "00:02:30",
    "offset": "00:01:00",
    "checks": [
        {   "id": "1",
            "name": "cpu",
            "status": 90
        },
        {
             "id": "2",
            "name": "memory",
            "status": 88
        },
        {
             "id": "3",
            "name": "apacheService",
            "status": 76
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that the id's for both objects are auto-generated which I think is part of the problem.

Comment: Dont you think posting the actual code that does the persistence may help? including showing what state the various objects are in at the point of persist ...

Answer (score 3):

Use the `CascadeType.MERGE` instead of `CascadeType.ALL`.